# What does "Impact" mean?

Tags: support, user-profile

I have this wierd impact thing where I can flag and that stuff, what does the Impact mean?
[image]

What does the 66 mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Impact" is an approximate measure of the number of people who have viewed your questions and answers. In your case, around 66 people have viewed your questions, which corresponds to the total view count.

Answer (score 2):

Hovering over the "Impact" (specifically the number of people reached) displays a tool tip telling you what it is:

[image: Tool tip]

Comment: I realize you are on an iPad and may not be able to hover over it.  Nonetheless.

Comment: I can tap on it